# Continuous function with no fixed point

Tags: continuity, fixed-point-theorems

I am searching an example of a continuous function $f: [0,1) \to [0,1)$  but f has no fixed point, that is, there is no point $x_0 \in [0,1)$ such that $f(x_0)\not= x_0 \forall x_0$.

Comment: Dont you mean ''$=$''

Comment: No, the function that have not fixed point

Answer (score 8):

Hint: consider polynomials of degree $1$ such that $f(1)=1$.

Comment: @Kalawa You asked for $f: [0,1) \to [0,1)$.  That doesn't allow $1$ as a value.

Comment: Still doesn't take $[0,1)$ into $[0,1)$.

Comment: f I tried the function $f(x)=\dfrac{x^2+1}{2}$, would it work?

Comment: Yes, that would also work.

Comment: Simply take, a linear polynomial, as @RobertIsrael has suggested. Any two none-parallel line, $y=mx+c$, $y=x$ will intersect in a single point. Make that intersection point as $(1,(f1))$. As an example, take, $y=0.99x+0.01$

Answer (score 0):

Always try to take motivation from picture.Draw straight line above line y=x which starts at (0,y) and ends at (1,1).y will be any value in (0,1) and you know equation of line passing through two points.

Answer (score 0):

Such function does not exist.

> Let $\phi(x)= f(x)-x$, $\phi(0)=f(0)\ge 0$ and $\phi(1)=f(1)-1<0$, therefore by ITV theorem there must be a $x_0\in [0;1)$ so that $\phi(x_0)=0$ which simply mean $f(x_0)=x_0$.

If you want a such function, you should avoid continuity, or the stability of $[0,1)$ by $f$.